# Why the edges of my rectangle is not parallel to axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, axis/.style={->,thick},thick, l/.style={dashed},tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[axis] (0, 0, 0) -- (3, 0, 0) node [right] {$X$};
\draw[axis] (0, 0, 0) -- (0, 3, 0) node [above] {$Y$};
\draw[axis] (0, 0, 0) -- (0, 0, 3) node [above] {$Z$};

\draw[tdplot_main_coords] (0,0,0) rectangle (3,3, 0);
\draw[->, thick] (1, 0,1) -- (1, 1.5, 1) node[above] {$\bar{n}_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to have the rectangle with edges that are parallel to axis. This is how I try to implement it. However, the rectangle's edges is not parallel to axis... looks like the original coordinate system is remained for the rectangle.

(I want to draw a plane that is laid in the xy-plane).

Comment: As a workaround you could of course do `\draw [red] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) -- (3,3,0) -- (3,0,0) -- cycle;`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Although interesting to know why rectangle does not work as expected

Comment: I would guess that the `rectangle` operation simply isn't defined for `tikz-3dplot`, but I'm not really that familiar with that package (or 3D in TikZ in general) so I cannot say for sure.

Comment: The rectangle is a special case of node, and nodes are 2D in nature.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the `rectangle` operation only works for 2D coordinates. A workaround  would be to draw the rectangle manually:

```
\draw [red] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) -- (3,3,0) -- (3,0,0) -- cycle;
```

Complete example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[axis/.style={->,thick},thick, l/.style={dashed},tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[axis] (0, 0, 0) -- (3, 0, 0) node [right] {$X$};
\draw[axis] (0, 0, 0) -- (0, 3, 0) node [above] {$Y$};
\draw[axis] (0, 0, 0) -- (0, 0, 3) node [above] {$Z$};

\draw[tdplot_main_coords] (0,0,0) rectangle (3,3, 0);
\draw [red] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) -- (3,3,0) -- (3,0,0) -- cycle;

\draw[->, thick] (1, 0,1) -- (1, 1.5, 1) node[above] {$\bar{n}_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```